# Find Max Hierarchyid in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, hierarchy

How to find `max` of `hierarchyid` type column?

for eg :

```
name  | user_hierarchyid
-------------------------
Craig | /
Steve | /1/
John  | /1/1/
Matt  | /1/1/1/
Sam   | /2/
Chris | /2/2/
```

I tried using `max(user_hierarchyid)` but it returns `/2/2/` but I want to get maximum of column hierarchically i.e. `/1/1/1/`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how heirrachy is calculated

Comment: @TheGameiswar : hierarchyid is calculated manually, according to their placement.

Comment: Technically, `/1/1/1/` *is* the hierarchical maximum.  Since you apparently want to use a different definition of '*hierarchical maximum*' than the standard, you will have to tell us what your definition of it is.

Comment: Hey! Have you tried any solutions from the answers below?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`GetLevel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677197.aspx) to get level and `TOP 1 WITH TIES` to get "max"(deepest) value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY user_hierarchyid.GetLevel() DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YFTI2004)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════════════════╗
║ name ║ user_hierarchyid ║
╠══════╬══════════════════╣
║ Matt ║ /1/1/1/          ║
╚══════╩══════════════════╝
```

---

Alternatively using `RANK()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY user_hierarchyid.GetLevel() DESC) AS rnk
      FROM mytable) AS s
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/LDI50265)**</kbd>

Comment: If I inserted one more row with user_hierarchyid  as `/1/1/2/`, both queries retruns `/1/1/1/` and `/1/1/2/`. Here I to get user_hierarchyid as `/1/1/2/` as it is the maximum hierarchically.

Comment: @PankajJawale Please define `maximum hierarchically` because at first I understand it as `deepest`. What if there be `/1/1/1` and `/1/2/1`?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like below

```
with cte
as
(
select name,user_hier_id,replace(user_hierarchyid,'/','') as rplcd
from table
)
select max(rplcd) from cte
```

Comment: What if there is value like `/10/11/` and it will be greater than `/1/1/2/`?

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT name, CAST(user_hierarchyid as hierarchyid) as user_hierarchyid
FROM (VALUES
('Craig', '/'),
('Steve', '/1/'),
('John', '/1/1/'),
('Matt', '/1/1/1/'),
('Sam', '/2/'),
('Chris', '/2/2/')
) as t(name, user_hierarchyid)
)

SELECT TOP 1
        name,
        CAST(user_hierarchyid as nvarchar(20)) as user_hierarchyid
FROM (
    SELECT  *,
            user_hierarchyid.GetAncestor(CASE WHEN user_hierarchyid.GetLevel() > 0 THEN user_hierarchyid.GetLevel()-1 ELSE user_hierarchyid.GetLevel() END ) as ga,
            user_hierarchyid.GetLevel() as gl
    FROM cte
    ) as t
ORDER BY Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ga ORDER BY gl,user_hierarchyid ) desc, ga DESC
```

Output:

```
name  user_hierarchyid
----- -----------------
Matt  /1/1/1/

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If you add row `('Dave', '/1/1/2/'),` then output will be `Dave  /1/1/2/`

If you add row `('Tony', '/2/2/1/'),` then output will be `Dave  /1/1/2/`

If you add row `('Ann', '/2/2/2/'),` then output will be `Ann  /2/2/2/`

If you add row `('Vic', '/1/1/1/1/'),` then output will be `Vic  /1/1/1/1/`